# measure to get all selected values in a slicer DAX Power Bi

Tags: powerbi, dax

[image]

I want to sum all the values on the matrix
in my current project the only value that shows is the "MAX" value AUG with 11 (power bi card)
I been using REMOVEFILTERS and ALLEXCEPT with no results so far.
The selected months in this scenario MAR, MAY, AUG are shown because I selected them with a slicer (DIMCALENDAR) DimCalendar[Month]
The "VALUE" is a measure, month by month the result of "VALUE" is correct.
**The correct answer for this question needs to be 36**  (power bi card)

Comment: Update your question with the DAX expression for the `VALUE` measure.

Comment: update: THIS IS THE MEASURE I'M WORKING ON

VALUE_MEASURE =
VAR varYear = SELECTEDVALUE(DimCalendar[Year])
VAR varMonth = MAX(DimCalendar[Month])
VAR varInitialDate = DATE(varYear,varMonth,1)
VAR varFinalDate = EOMONTH(varInitialDate,0)
RETURN
CALCULATE([ROOT_MEASURE],FACT_TABLE[period] >= varInitialDate, FACT_TABLE[period] <= varFinalDate)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect in your measure you have a `MAX(Table[Month])` or a `SELECTEDVALUE(Table[Month])`.

Try updating it to:

```
VALUE_MEASURE =
  var yr = SELECTEDVALUE(DimCalendar[Year])
  return
    CALCULATE(
      [ROOT_MEASURE],
      YEAR(FACT_TABLE[period]) = yr &&
      MONTH(FACT_TABLE[period]) IN DISTINCT(DimCalendar[Month])
    )
```